# WHERE, LIKE OR AND NOT operators not returning expected result

Tags: sql, mysqli

I am trying to get the results where the kids column is NULL but for some reason the sql returns all the matching LIKE OR rows, even ones where the kids column is not null, ive tried the code below.

This SQL returns a result as expected

```
SELECT `name`, `middlename`, `kids` 
FROM persons 
WHERE (name LIKE '%brenda%' OR middlename LIKE '%smith%') 
   OR (name LIKE '%kent%' OR middlename LIKE '%smith') 
   AND kids IS NOT NULL
```

This SQL returns the same results as the above even tho the kids column contains data and is not null?

```
SELECT `name`, `middlename`, `kids` 
FROM persons 
WHERE (name LIKE '%brenda%' OR middlename LIKE '%smith%') 
   OR (name LIKE '%kent%' OR middlename LIKE '%smith%') 
   AND kids IS NULL
```

I tried this aswell but it still returns a result even tho the kids column is not null

```
SELECT `name`, `middlename`, `kids` 
FROM persons 
WHERE (name LIKE '%brenda%' OR middlename LIKE '%smith%' AND kids IS NULL) 
   OR (name LIKE '%kent%' OR middlename LIKE '%smith%' AND kids IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your parenthesis mixed up.
Use parenthesis to separate the `OR` conditions from the `AND` conditions - there is no point of separating `OR` from `OR`.
Try this query instead:

```
SELECT `name`, `middlename`, `kids` 
FROM persons 
WHERE (name LIKE '%brenda%' 
    OR name LIKE '%kent%' 
    OR middlename LIKE '%smith') 
AND kids IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

parentheses are required around all the `OR` conditions:

```
    SELECT 
        `name`, `middlename`, `kids` 
    FROM 
        persons 
    WHERE 
       (name LIKE '%brenda%' OR middlename LIKE '%smith%' 
        OR name LIKE '%kent%' OR middlename LIKE '%smith) 
       AND kids IS NOT NULL
```